# IOS: LazyLoad image From Json

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, lazy-loading, nsjsonserialization

i'm new on this programming language... i try to consume json from some servers, after success consume all information, now i've problem tho show "lazyload" image into tableviewcell

i use [AsyncImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView) to make it happen, and here my code

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView :(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NetraCell *cell =(NetraCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell==nil){
        cell=[[NetraCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

        //common settings
        cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 44.0f, 44.0f);
        cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

        ///get url image from url
        //NSString *path=[[[Deals_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];

        ////convert image into NSDATA
    //  NSData* imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: path]];
        ////read NSData Image
    //  UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
        //////set rounded imager with NetraImage

    //  image=[ImageManipulator makeRoundCornerImage:image : 30 : 30];

        ////show image into UItableviewCell
    //  cell.imageView.image=image;

    }
    else{
        //cancel loading previous image for cell
        [[AsyncImageLoader sharedLoader] cancelLoadingImagesForTarget:cell.imageView];
    }
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png"];
    cell.imageView.imageURL = [[[imageURLs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"image"]objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];

    NSString *price=[[[somearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"price"]objectForKey:@"formatted"];
    ///call image from JSOn


    ///draw to tableviewcell
    if(price!=NULL){
        cell.detailTextLabel.text= [[[Deals_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"price"]objectForKey:@"formatted"]; //1 draw the price
        //[cell release]
    }
    else{
    cell.detailTextLabel.text= @"Call";

    }
    //draw headline
    cell.textLabel.text=[[Deals_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"headline"];
    ///draw image


         [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=NO;
    return  cell;
}
```

this line is my path of immage

```
//NSString *path=[[[Deals_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
```

and this is the default method to assign pic into uitableviewcell

```
cell.imageView.imageURL = [imageURLs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

but when i try this method

```
cell.imageView.imageURL = [[[imageURLs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"image"]objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
```

its error, the main question is

1. why error? is that my remote image path wrong? or my method wrong

Need your help please :) many thanks

Comment: log the urls before assigning to imageView, and check in ur PC browser does it has any image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once check for whether you are assigning  appropriate imageurl to cell image url or not in your code,[[[imageURLs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"image"]objectForKey:@"thumbnail"], and go through this,it may help for you
  [lazy loading of images in UITableView cell](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Listings/Classes_RootViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394-Classes_RootViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_12)